# passing form input data to another form through session

Tags: php, forms, laravel

i am new in laravel,  i want to do a step by step form filling, 
i want to  pass data from one form to the other through session

**form one:**

```
<form action="{{URL::route('addUser')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">            
   <select  name="year">
     <option>Select</option>
     {{$options}}
  </select>             
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"></button>
</form>
```

**form two**

```
<form action="{{URL::route('addUser')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="text" name="check_number" />
</form>
```

**my routes**

```
Route::get('/admin/addUser',array('uses'=>'UserController@addUser','as'=>'addUser'));
Route::post('/admin/addUser',array('uses'=>'UserController@postUser'))->before('csrf');
```

i just want to pass a year input value to the next page and use it there

how can i do this?

Comment: You are sending both forms to the same url? that does make things complicated.

Comment: then what are you suggesting, remember am new at this

Comment: seems like you need to have a look at [the manual](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session)

Comment: If you just want to pass a year input value to the next page and use it there you should use `Input::get('year')`. Disregard Jerodev comment, the urls are not the same because of the http verb.